# Custom bool field in phabricator

Tags: customization, phabricator, maniphest

I'm adding a custom boolean field to maniphest  and it's working fine.
But i need queries to filter on that value, and it does not work.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Custom field:

```
{"sql":{"name":"Has Sql","type":"bool","search":true,"default":false,"strings":  {"search.require":"yes"}}}
```

The tasks can set the value to nothing or true, but when i try to search for tasks that has this value set to yes, none is returned.

Is there anything i'm missing ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try choosing another name for the field.  Maybe "sql" is getting scrubbed.

I took your custom field definition and altered it to this:

```
{"xx-custom":{"name":"Has custom","type":"bool","search":true,"default":false,"strings":  {"search.require":"yes"}}}
```

I can successfully search on that field in the query editor.  I do find that my options for searching on this field are "(Any)" or "Yes".  I never get the "No" option.